# UIImageView reverts back to original frame

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

My homePage `viewController` opens to a `UIImageView` of a logo. `viewDidAppear` then runs two animations. A translation of the logo up, and a fadein of a `UITextField`. When a user clicks on the `UITextField textFieldDidBeginEditing` runs and animates the view's frame up (to allow the user to see the `UITextField` that would have been covered by the keyboard). When the user clicks anywhere off keyboard `textFieldDidEndEditing` runs and animates the view's frame back down. After `textFieldDidEndEditing` runs my `UIImageView` is back in its original position (before it's animation up). Why does this occur, and how should I fix it? Thanks.

```
static const CGFloat STARTPAGE_ANIMATION_TIME = 0.5;
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear:");

    CGRect logoFrame = logoImage.frame;
    logoFrame.origin.y = 130;
    [UIImageView animateWithDuration:STARTPAGE_ANIMATION_TIME delay:STARTPAGE_ANIMATION_TIME options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        logoImage.frame = logoFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"logoImageAnimation");
    }];

    [UIImageView animateWithDuration:STARTPAGE_ANIMATION_TIME delay:STARTPAGE_ANIMATION_TIME options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        searchField.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"searchFieldAnimation");
    }];
}


CGFloat ANIMATED_DISTANCE = 200;
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing:");

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= ANIMATED_DISTANCE;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION animations:^{
        self.view.frame = viewFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"frameAnimationUp");
    }];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidEndEditing:");

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += ANIMATED_DISTANCE;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION animations:^{
        self.view.frame = viewFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"frameAnimationDown");
    }];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan:withEvent:");
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: what are you expecting to see after textFieldDidEndEditing runs?

Comment: Are you targeting iOS 5 and above? If so, use the block version of doing animations: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW111 . Also, you can combine several animations within a block, and call it on UIView not on UIImageView or other subclasses. A tip to make the code clearer.

Comment: Actually, iOS 4 and above should be using the block based.

Comment: Also, this would be much easier if you just put everything on a scrollView and set the contentOffset.y by the height of the keyboard

Comment: @sergio The keyboard gone, and the logoImage in the same frame it was in after its animation.

Comment: @Kekoa I've posted a revised edition of the code using blocks.

Comment: @jmstone I would prefer not to do that, because I don't want users to be able to scroll on that view.

Comment: Just set the contentSize property of the scrollView to the size of the screen initial. No scrolling will happen.

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with the animations affecting each other. It depends on the timing if you are beginning editing while an animation is happening, adding and subtracting a value from `y` is unpredictable.

Save the original frame on a property before the move and reset the frame afterwards. This will yield much more predictable results when you are dealing with several overlapping animations.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean. Can you show me an example?